# Should Function objects be cached?

Tags: java, performance, instantiation

Let's say I'm using a transformation method that takes a `Collection` and a `Function` object, such as [the one in Guava's `Collections2`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html). I pass an anonymous `Function` implementation defined inline in the parameter list.

Is there any justifiable reason for caching the `Function` instance if this transformation is used a large amount of times? Would it make a sufficiently significant difference to outweigh the reduced readability from separating definition and use of the `Function`?

Comment: What do your tests tell you? Only you can determine whether it makes a difference in your specific case. That will depend on various factors, including just how often it's called and how much work is done each time. Oh, and readability is somewhat subjective too - if you give the function a good name, you may well find it makes the code using it *more* readable than having an anonymous inner class interfering with the code.

Comment: Personally I would say the separating the `Function` makes the code _more_ readable. `FluentIterable.from(myListOfApples).filter(new IsGreenApple()).transForm(new ToJuice())` for example is more readable than trying to work out what the 10-odd lines of each anonymous class do. Performance wise, test test test!